# get response via python scrapy package

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

I am very new in Python.
i want to send a http request by scrapy in python and get the response in a variable.
I don't know how to catch response text.

```
from scrapy import Request
url = '***'

headers = {
    "authority": "***",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "authorization": "BasicAuthentication ***",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "origin": "***",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "referer": "***",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7"
}

body = '***'

request = Request(
    url=url,
    method='POST',
    dont_filter=True,
    headers=headers,
    body=body,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a spider project or a crawler process in order for scrapy to make requests. Scrapy will start several other processes in order to execute requests, so it seems it's not the best choice for what you need. You can have an overview of how scrapy works [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html).

If your intention is to just make a request in the middle of a python code and work with's reponse I suggest you to use [requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

If you want to learn more about scrapy, start with the [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

Comment: thank you, but i try with requests package and it seems too slow in compare with google chrome. in the chrome it takes 20 ms to send a request and in python 100 ms. because of this I cope with scrapy. @rea